# Whether to place a preposition after "кроме: "кроме авося" or "кроме на авось"?

Tags: грамматика

> Разве ничего нельзя сделать?

In response to this, I just said in conversation:

> Кто знает. Правда, боюсь, надеяться **кроме авося** больше не **на** что.

I'm now wondering if I should have placed the preposition "на" after "кроме", too?

> Кто знает. Правда, боюсь, надеяться **кроме на авось** больше не **на** что.

In hindsight, I think I was tempted to use "на" as early on in this clause as possible, as I started it with "надеяться".

Comment: As mentioned in an answer, it looks like the noun "авось" happens to add an extra layer of grammatical complexity to my question. So aside from the question of whether "авось" should be invariable declension-wise in this specific instance, we might, just for the sake of argument, be better off substituting some other noun: "надеяться **кроме помощи его** больше не на что" vs "надеяться **кроме на помощь его** больше не на что".

Comment: "кроме авося" is grammatically incorrect, but I absolutely can imagine it being used and reused in linguistically creative places like internet forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variant is a great humorous sentence, i like it. Not because it's ostensibly incorrect but because it sounds witty, with tongue in cheek.

The preposition **кроме** before anything but a (pro)noun/numeral/adjective in any case but Genitive requires conjunction **как** - **кроме как**

**`кроме нас`** but **`кроме как у нас/про нас/нам/нами`**
**`кроме синего`** but **`кроме как синий/-им/-ему`**
**`кроме утра`** but **`кроме как утром`** etc.

Therefore, although you beat me to it with your comment while i was typing up this response, the stylistically correct version is

> Правда, боюсь, надеяться **кроме как** на авось больше не на что.

or in a more relaxed order

> Правда, боюсь, **кроме как** на авось надеяться больше не на что.

But i still prefer your original one.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid form is "на авось" - in this usage it's not declined anyhow and stays exactly in the same form. "Авось" is declined in some extremely rarely used phrases, mostly sayings like "от авося добра не жди" or "авося жданки съели" or "авосю не вовсе верь".

It would be safe to say that most likely the only place one can encounter declined "авось" is dictionary.